# If statement within a function is skipped, despite conditions being fufilled

Tags: python-3.x

I was making a miles to km / km to miles converter and when run the converter skips over the `if` statement even when the conditions appear to be fulfilled, and instead executes the `else` statement.

Here's the code:

```
"""Converts mi to km."""
print("Welcome to the converter!")
miorkm = input("Km to mi, or mi to km: ").lower
val = input("How many Km or Mi: ")

def converter(inpu2):
    """Converts the value."""
    output = 0
    if miorkm == "km":
        output = int(val) * 0.621
    else:
        output = int(val) * 1.609
    return output
print(converter(miorkm))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please add test cases with their output.

Comment: You are mixing arguments and access to global variables -- very ugly style and errorprone. Redesign the function to use two arguments and access them (your `inpu2` is not used at all!)

Comment: For example, inputting km on miorkm and 10 on the val inputs would print 16.09, as would inputting mi and then 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.lower` should be `.lower()`. It was returning a function, which `!= 'km'`.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it. I knew it would be something simple like this :P.

Comment: @magicguy38 No problem! Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes =]

Answer (score 3):

Learn to use a debugger.  `pdb` is a simple console debugger, but there are plenty of GUI ones that are easier to use.

First, kick off the debugger in your script.

```
C:\>py -m pdb test.py
> c:\test.py(1)<module>()
-> """Converts mi to km."""
```

`n` executes a line and does not go into calls.  We'll advance to the first input line:

```
(Pdb) n
> c:\test.py(2)<module>()
-> print("Welcome to the converter!")
(Pdb) n
Welcome to the converter!
> c:\test.py(3)<module>()
-> miorkm = input("Km to mi, or mi to km: ").lower
```

Executing this line will prompt for `miorkm`:

```
(Pdb) n
Km to mi, or mi to km: km
> c:\test.py(4)<module>()
-> val = input("How many Km or Mi: ")
```

Check the value just entered:

```
(Pdb) miorkm
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x0000000002B65E68>
```

That isn't `"km"`!  You assigned the `str.lower` method to the variable.  Call the method instead with `.lower()`.

But in case you don't notice this, keep going:

```
(Pdb) n
How many Km or Mi: 10
> c:\test.py(7)<module>()
-> def converter(inpu2):
(Pdb) n
> c:\test.py(15)<module>()
-> print(converter(miorkm))
```

Here we don't want `n` to execute the whole line.  We want `s` to step into the converter function:

```
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> c:\test.py(7)converter()
-> def converter(inpu2):
```

Now we are in the `converter()` function.  Look for problems...

```
(Pdb) s
> c:\test.py(9)converter()
-> output = 0
(Pdb) s
> c:\test.py(10)converter()
-> if miorkm == "km":
(Pdb) s
> c:\test.py(13)converter()
-> output = int(val) * 1.609
```

This went to the wrong line!  `miorkm` was supposed to be `"km"`.  Check it:

```
(Pdb) miorkm
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x0000000002B65E68>
```

A faster way to find the problem is to note you always go to the `else:` statement.  Edit the code to `import pdb`, then set a breakpoint before the `if` with `pdb.set_trace()`:

```
import pdb
"""Converts mi to km."""
print("Welcome to the converter!")
miorkm = input("Km to mi, or mi to km: ").lower
val = input("How many Km or Mi: ")


def converter(inpu2):
    """Converts the value."""
    output = 0
    pdb.set_trace()
    if miorkm == "km":
        output = int(val) * 0.621
    else:
        output = int(val) * 1.609
    return output
print(converter(miorkm))
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the converter!
Km to mi, or mi to km: km
How many Km or Mi: 10
> c:\users\metolone\desktop\test.py(12)converter()
-> if miorkm == "km":
```

After it hits the breakpoint, check the value of `miorkm`:
    (Pdb) miorkm

A final method...the easiest.  Add a `print` before the `if`:

```
print('miorkm =',miorkm)
if(...)
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the converter!
Km to mi, or mi to km: km
How many Km or Mi: 10
miorkm = <built-in method lower of str object at 0x000000000226B1B8>
16.09
```